# Calculate values in 2 DataGridView cells - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I can't figure out how to solve this. I wanna calculate the sum of 2 cells in a DataGridView, divide their sum by 2 and then write that value inside a specific cell. Whenever I click the button it show me this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

How do I solve this error? My code is this:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int total;
        foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            total = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2]));
            dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[column.Index].Value = total;
        }
    }
```

Please help me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are converting Cell to integer and that is no possible use `Cell.Value` to get cell value.

Change

```
total = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2]));
```

To this

```
total = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[1].Value));
```

Comment: Thanks! That is fixed but now it show and error an the next line :) It says this >Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Check row number `dataGridView1.Rows[4]` there should be row available at 4th position.

Comment: Thank you so much! My DataGridView had only one row and I somehow got confused by the difference between a row and a column.

Comment: Also, how do I do this for all the rows, not just a specific one?

Comment: Make a loop... Easy :)